# How can I use the 200 seconds exposure time in Raspberry Pi HQ camera?

Tags: camera

I would like to use the Raspberry pi HQ camera for astrophotography. I have read in this answer and comments on [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/116765/new-pi-camera-any-good-for-astrophotography)  that I should be able to use a maximum exposure time of 200 seconds.
This is also stated in [the camera guide book](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/books/camera-guide/) (pdf) on page 115:

> Shutter speed

```
--shutter or -ss
```

Sets the shutter speed to the specified value (in microseconds). The upper limit is around 6000000 µs (6 s) for CM v1; 10000000 µs (10 s) for CM v2; 200000000 µs (200s) for HQ Camera.

Can somebody explain how to use 200s of exposure time? In this [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/116765/new-pi-camera-any-good-for-astrophotography/117351#117351) they mentioned, using sudo rpi-update is enough to unlock this functionality. But after running that command I can't see a difference between photos using the 200s and 10s exposure time.

This question was orginally in  [photo stack exchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/117803/how-can-i-use-the-200-seconds-exposure-time-in-raspberry-pi-hq-camera), but nobody has an idea.

Solution: I found it [on this page.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=272658&p=1665340&hilit=astrophotography#p1665340)

```
time ( raspistill -t 10 -md 3 -bm -ex off -ag 1 --shutter 239000000 -ISO 800 -st -o image.jpg )
```

Comment: *"I can't see a difference between photos using the 200s and 10s exposure time."* -- To confirm, try running `raspistill` with `time` (you may have to `apt install time`): `time raspistill -ss ...`.